# Testing cancan abilities with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, cancan

I'm new to RSpec and Factory Girl so I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

I would like to figure out how to incorporate Factory Girl into the approach to testing cancan abilities which is recommend on the [cancan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities):

```
require "cancan/matchers"
# create user
ability = Ability.new(user)
ability.should_not be_able_to(:destroy, Project.new)
```

I put this code in spec/models/ability_spec.rb and tried creating the user with the same Factory Girl method that is working in my controller specs:

```
  admin = create(:user)
```

However RSpec gives the error "undefined method `create'"  The same thing happens when I do FactoryGirl.create(:user).

**Update**

In specs/spec_helper.rb I have:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: how did you configure your app. to use FactoryGirl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Very embarrassing.  I missed something simple - not putting this inside a proper it call.

Only consolation is that I'm [not the first.](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/220)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put it in your **spec_helper.rb**

```
config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
```

Comment: Thanks Said.  I have this already.  I've updated my question to reflect this.